# Getting the 557th element of a table

Tags: homework

> Make a table with elements $\sin(\sqrt{8 n}/4) + r\, $for $n$ from $1$ to $1000$, where $r$ is a random real number between $-0.1$ and $0.1$ that is different for each value of $n$. Also make a plot of all the points of this table. What is the $557^{th}$ element of this table?

Everything is working well, but I can't get the 557th element of the table. I've tried to use the `Select` command.

```
Select[TableSin[Sqrt[(a*n)/4]] + Random[Real, {-0.1, 0.1}], {n, 1, 1000}] ,557]
```

but it's not working. I can't figure out how to fix it.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Look at `Take` in the documentation

Comment: Sounds more like `Part` is what he is looking for.

Comment: My professor gave the hint: use "Select"

Comment: And we gave you two more hints... `Select` would be a really terrible way to do it and I would not advise it. You can probably teach your professor something new today :)

Comment: `Select` is for picking out all elements in a list that match some criteria. Using it to simply get the 557th elements is making things complicated.

Comment: Here's another hint: look up `Extract`

Comment: @MrAlpha and terribly inefficient as the position does not exist as part of the list ...

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, in general a really terrible way. In this particular narrow case though, given the structure of the elements (he hasn't defined `a`) and primality of 557, `FreeQ` can aid us...

Comment: @rm-rf actually, my thought is that since the element count is not naturally part of a list (in general), then to use `Select` one would have to somehow associate an element with its position.

Comment: @rm-rf I had something a little more robust in mind involving `Range` and `Transpose`, but I won't mention details seeing how it is homework, and all.

Comment: The question was to find the 557th element of the table. That, quite simply, translates into: `Table[Sin[Sqrt[(a*n)/4]]+Random[Real,{-0.1,0.1}],{n,1,1000}][[557]]`. Note the missing opening `[` in the originally posted code. Also, the posted code uses a variable `a`; in order to plot, you need a specific numeric value.

Comment: The problem specifies "_different_" random reals to be used. Even for such a small list length as 1000, so far as I'm aware there's no guarantee that Mathematica will provide distinct ones. To be extra certain (if it's important), you can take additional measures, e.g.: generate a considerably longer list of random reals; use `Union` to extract just the distinct entries; and then, if necessary, shorten that result to the 1000 you need. However, the actual intention of the problem statement may have been merely not to use the same randomly chosen number for each item.

Comment: @murray `a` is supposed to be 8. There is also another error in the OPs code. It should read `Sin[Sqrt[8 n]/4]` instead of `Sin[Sqrt[(8 n) / 4]]` if one follows the description in the task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Select` is wrong in this case, you can't use it to get the n-th element of a list without using additional helper functions.

You'll get the most out of this exercise by looking at `Part`, which is a very flexible function for extracting elements out of a list based on their position, for example

```
x = {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55}

(* Explicit syntax. Extracts the 3rd element out of a list
   (first element has index 1). *)
Part[x, 3]
(* ==> 2 *)

(* Syntactic sugar: using [[ ]] for Part *)
x[[3]]
(* ==> 2 *)
```

`Part` can do much more, e.g. extracting ranges, submatrices and so on. While not necessary to solve this problem, I highly recommend reading a few paragraphs in the Mathematica help - you *will* need it again soon. :-)

For the fun of it, here's the easiest way of doing the same task with `Select` instead of `Part` I could come up with:

```
x = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}
Select[
    MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, x],
    Last[#] == 3 &
] // First // First
(* ==> 2 *)
```

(Manually index the list wasting a ton of memory, then pick the element and discard the indexing again.)

Comment: That `Select` method is just silly... Go Syntactic sugar!